# How to save Images with two different dimensions using plupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, plupload

I am using Plupload plugin to upload multiple images as we have option to resize images on the client side and I would like to upload images with original size and save them to seperate folder and the resized images to another folder.

Can anyone suggest me how to procee further?
Here is my code:

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim chunk As Integer = If(context.Request("chunk") IsNot Nothing, Integer.Parse(context.Request("chunk")), 0)
    Dim fileName As String = If(context.Request("name") IsNot Nothing, context.Request("name"), String.Empty)

    Dim fileUpload As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files(0)

    Dim uploadPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/uploads")
    Using fs = New FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName), If(chunk = 0, FileMode.Create, FileMode.Append))
        Dim buffer = New Byte(fileUpload.InputStream.Length - 1) {}
        fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

        fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
    End Using

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    context.Response.Write("Success")
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property
```

This my script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Setup flash version
        $("#flash_uploader").pluploadQueue({
            // General settings
            runtimes: 'flash',
            url: 'upload.ashx',
            max_file_size: '10mb',
            chunk_size: '1mb',
            unique_names: true,
            filters: [
        { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg" }
    ],

            // Resize images on clientside if we can
            resize: { width: 800, height: 600, quality: 90 },

            // Flash settings
            flash_swf_url: 'js/plupload.flash.swf',

            init: { StateChanged: function (up) {
                // Called when the state of the queue is changed
                if (up.state == plupload.STOPPED) {
                    $("#btnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }
            }

        });
    var uploader = $('#flash_uploader').pluploadQueue();
    uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, res) {
        $('#showfilelist').append("<div id=" + file.id + "><a href='uploads/" + file.target_name + "' target='_blank'><img src='uploads/" + file.target_name + "' border='0'/><br>" + file.name + "</a><br>(" + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ") <span></span></div>");

});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Resizing an image
// Inputs [ new image size (Height,Width), Origial file path & name, new file path & name ]

 ResizeImage(int height,int width, string inputFile, string outputFile)
{
            var img = Image.FromFile(inputFile);
            Image imagThumb = null;
            imagThumb = img.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, null, new IntPtr());
            imagThumb.Save(outputFile);
 }
```

input and output files can be access from path you saving the images

```
eg.var input = Server.MapPath("~/images/imagename");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply actually this is a handler and we cant proceed with this so is there any possibility to append this code for the above handler.